# One-way switch in verilog

Tags: verilog

I need to hold a value so that once it switches to one, it won't switch back to zero.

I am trying to make a Hangman game for an FPGA board. To do so, I have a constant `onesLetter` which is the correct letter to be displayed. The user has to guess letters. Once the `onesLetter` has been guessed correctly, I want to display it and keep displaying it during other guesses (not reverting back to the default display).

Here is what I have come up with:

```
// onesLetter is a constant we are checking against
// tempBooleanOnes represents if letter is currently being guessed
// tempSeg is input to check against onesLetter
// boolean is an input bit
wire tempBooleanOnes = (boolean && (onesLetter == tempSeg));

// Represent whether letter has been guessed or not
wire booleanOnes;

// Whether letter has been guessed or is being guessed
assign booleanOnes = (booleanOnes) || (tempBooleanOnes);
```

That is the expression I need to implement. However, I get an error saying I can't use `booleanOnes` for both the assigned wire and the expression. I've tried using a module `register (output, input, clock, enable, reset)` that I've implemented, with the enable being `~booleanOnes` (do not overwrite when already 1, or already guessed) and the output being `booleanOnes`, but that also raises an error.

This is the code for the register module I have tried in place of the `assign` statement.

```
register regOnes(booleanOnes, tempBooleanOnes, clk, ~booleanOnes, 1'b0);
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you use the register (which is the right idea)? Can you post the full module with `tempBoleansOnes` and others as well as the implementation of `register` module so we can better pinpoint your error?

Comment: with this expression you are creating a feed back loop, buffer, which output is connected to its own input. So, it makes no hardware sense. You need to create a  model which uses a state machine that does what you need. That also means employing clocks and flops.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this:

```
assign booleanOnes = (booleanOnes) || (tempBooleanOnes);
```

Since you're assigning to and from the same wire.

This code will set `booleanOnes` to 1 and will never be reset.

```
reg booleanOnes = 0; 
always @* begin
   if(boolean && (onesLetter == tempSeg)) begin
       booleanOnes = 1;
   end
end
```